# Como subir uma aplicação web (html e css) pra um servidor local?

Tags: html, servidor

Afim de usar o Livestyle (ferramenta que atualiza o css em tempo real no browser), preciso subir minha aplicação web (html + css) pra um servidor local, mas como posso fazer isso?

Sempre usei o Tomcat pra minhas aplicações PHP e JAVA, mas nunca pra html puro.

Obrigado!

Comment: Use o servidor embutido do php dentro da pasta do projeto. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

o **HTML**, **CSS** e até mesmo **JAVASCRIPT** (utilizado no front-end) são compilados por seu navegador (ex.: Chrome, Firefox, Edge...); então você pode simplesmente arrastar seu arquivo HTML para o navegador que ele irá abrir e os respectivos caminhos serão respeitados.

Ao arrastar você verá o caminho físico de sua máquina na URL.

Caso seja necessário ter o caminho 127.0.0.1 você pode usar diversas soluções, como o Wamp: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/ (supondo que você use Linux)

Comment: entendo, porem para eu ver a mudança no css eu preciso atualizar a pagina, e com o Livestyle essa mudança acontece assim que eu modifico o css, porem apenas se estiver num servidor local (127.0.0.1 por exemplo)

Comment: Entendi, eu uso o Wamp, coloquei o link na resposta, funciona bem legal